# Jquery / PrimeFaces change value of dropdown

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I need to change the value of a drop down in response to a onChange event - using Prime Faces and JQuery for this purpose - the following is the sample code I am using which does not appear to be working as expected( the status of my drop down does not change as I need it to)

```
if (myCondition == 'Y') {
    var handle = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(myComponent));
    handle.prop('value', 'Y');
            handle.attr('value', 'Y');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JQuery [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to change the value of a select element:

```
if (myCondition == 'Y') {
    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(myComponent)).val('Y');
}
```

Note: The name of the `escapeCliendId()` function is a little misleading. It returns the element's `id` (properly escaped), but with a `#` character prepended, so it really returns an id selector. ([reference](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-get-jsf-id-via-jquery/))

Comment: PrimeFaces.escapeClientId function is from primefaces.js, , it’s just a wrapper js function to replace the colon “:” with placing a double backslashes in front of it. `escapeClientId:function(a){return"#"+a.replace(/:/g,"\\:")}`